# Convert REST Spring Boot Example to SOAP

Tags: spring, rest, soap, spring-boot

Is it possible to easily convert the REST WS example (http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to a SOAP WS? What needs to be done to convert that example?

Comment: Did you see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115205/spring-boot-with-spring-ws-soap-endpoint-not-accessable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is easy possible to convert this (simple) example to SOAP.

#### Migrate

To get from [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/tree/main/complete) to (something similar like) this ([guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-producing-web-service)|[repository](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-producing-web-service/tree/main/complete)), we need to:

1. adjust build.gradle to:

   ```gradle
   plugins {
     id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.0' // update to latest
     id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
     id 'java'
   }

   group = 'com.stackoverflow' // re-brand ;)
   version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
   sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }

   // complete chunk from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-producing-web-service/tree/main/complete/build.gradle
   sourceSets {
     main {
       java {
         srcDir 'src/main/java'
         srcDir 'build/generated-sources/jaxb'
       }
     }
   }

   task genJaxb {
     ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
     ext.schema = "src/main/resources/greeting.xsd" // replace countries.xsd from soap stackoverflow with our xsd

     outputs.dir sourcesDir

     doLast() {
       project.ant {
         taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
             classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
         mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)

         xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
           arg(value: "-wsdl")
           produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
         }
       }
     }
   }

   compileJava.dependsOn genJaxb

   configurations {
     jaxb
   }

   dependencies {
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
     testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    // addtional dependencies
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
     implementation 'wsdl4j:wsdl4j'
     jaxb('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc')
   }
   // end of chunk
   test {
     useJUnitPlatform()
   }
   ```

   , which is: original build.gradle + instructions for jaxb + additional dependencies.
2. settings.gradle we change (correctly but not obligatory) to:

   ```gradle
   rootProject.name = 'soap-service'
   ```
3. We introduce src/main/resources/greeting.xsd with following content:

   ```xml
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/"
               targetNamespace="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/" elementFormDefault="qualified">

     <xs:element name="getGreetingRequest">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" default="from XSD" />
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>

     <xs:element name="getGreetingResponse">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="greeting" type="tns:greeting"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>

     <xs:complexType name="greeting">
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
         <xs:element name="content" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:schema>
   ```

   , trying to mimic the REST endpoint and model as SOAP.
4. (Best) we delete all (main & test) sources in:

   - src/main/java/com/example/restservice
   - src/test/java/com/example/restservice

   , to replace them.
5. This will be our SpringBootApplication + Configuration:

   ```java
   package com.stackoverflow.soapservice;       

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
   import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
   import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
   import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
   import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
   import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
   import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;
   @EnableWs
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class SOAPServiceApplication {

     public static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/";

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(SOAPServiceApplication.class, args);
     }

     @Bean
     public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
       MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
       servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
       servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
       return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*");
     }

     @Bean(name = "greetings")
     public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema greetingSchema) {
       DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
       wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("GreetingPort");
       wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
       wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(NAMESPACE_URI);
       wsdl11Definition.setSchema(greetingSchema);
       return wsdl11Definition;
     }

     @Bean
     public XsdSchema greetingsSchema() {
       return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("greeting.xsd"));
     }
   }
   ```
6. The endpoint class:

   ```java
    package com.stackoverflow.soapservice;

    import com.stackoverflow.greeting_soap.GetGreetingRequest;
    import com.stackoverflow.greeting_soap.GetGreetingResponse;
    import com.stackoverflow.greeting_soap.Greeting;
    import static com.stackoverflow.soapservice.SOAPServiceApplication.NAMESPACE_URI;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
    import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
    import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
    import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
    import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

    @Endpoint
    public class GreetingEndpoint {

      private static final String HELLO_TPL = "Hello, %s!";
      private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong();

      @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getGreetingRequest")
      @ResponsePayload
      public GetGreetingResponse sayHello(@RequestPayload GetGreetingRequest request) {
        GetGreetingResponse response = new GetGreetingResponse();

        Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
        greeting.setContent(
          String.format(
           HELLO_TPL, request.getName() == null ? "World" : request.getName()
          )
        );
        greeting.setId(COUNTER.incrementAndGet());

        response.setGreeting(greeting);
        return response;
      }
    }
   ```
7. And a test:

   ```java
   package com.stackoverflow.soapservice;
   import com.stackoverflow.greeting_soap.GetGreetingRequest;
   import com.stackoverflow.greeting_soap.GetGreetingResponse;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
   import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
   import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

   import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
   import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
   import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
   import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
   import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;

   @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
   class GreetingEndpointTest {

    private static final QName NS_NAME_QNAME = QName.valueOf(
      String.format("{%s}%s", SOAPServiceApplication.NAMESPACE_URI, "name")
    );

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

     @Bean
     public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
      final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
      marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.stackoverflow.greeting_soap");
      marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
       {
        put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
       }
      });
      return marshaller;
     }

     @Bean
     public WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
      return new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
     }
    }

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port = 0;

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate ws;

    @Test
    public void testSendAndReceive() {
     // Given:
     final String NAME = "Test";
     GetGreetingRequest request = new GetGreetingRequest();
     JAXBElement<String> elem = new JAXBElement<>(NS_NAME_QNAME, String.class, NAME);
     request.setName(elem);

     // When:
     GetGreetingResponse result = (GetGreetingResponse) ws.marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:"
       + port + "/ws", request);

     // Then:
     assertThat(result != null);
     assertThat(result.getGreeting() != null);
     assertThat(result.getGreeting().getContent() != null);
     assertThat(result.getGreeting().getContent().startsWith("Hello")
       && result.getGreeting().getContent().contains(NAME));
    }

    // ... see at github
   }
   ```

#### Build

With JDK 1.8:

```java
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk/8
```

For higher JDK versions up to 11, we'd have to adjust dependencies.
How to shift this sample up-to-date (jdk-17-LTS)? ... ["Null Problemo!"](https://github.com/xerx593/soq21320913/tree/jdk17)

Clean, test and bootRun:

```java
./gradlew clean test bootRun
```

When first time imported into our IDE, a "priming build", respectively `./gradlew genJaxb` will be useful (/generate the jaxb classes).

#### Use

- get the wsdl:

  ```bash
  curl http://localhost:8080/ws/greetings.wsdl
  ```

  gets us (unformatted):

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:sch="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/" 
    targetNamespace="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/">
    <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
        targetNamespace="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/">
        <xs:element name="getGreetingRequest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" default="from XSD" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="getGreetingResponse">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="greeting" type="tns:greeting"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:complexType name="greeting">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="content" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getGreetingResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getGreetingResponse" name="getGreetingResponse"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getGreetingRequest">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getGreetingRequest" name="getGreetingRequest"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="GreetingPort">
      <wsdl:operation name="getGreeting">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getGreetingRequest" name="getGreetingRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getGreetingResponse" name="getGreetingResponse"></wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="GreetingPortSoap11" type="tns:GreetingPort">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="getGreeting">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getGreetingRequest">
          <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getGreetingResponse">
          <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="GreetingPortService">
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:GreetingPortSoap11" name="GreetingPortSoap11">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws"/>
      </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
  ```
- send a request:

  ```xml
  curl --header "content-type: text/xml" -d @request.xml http://localhost:8080/ws > output.xml
  ```

  with this ./request.xml:

  ```xml
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:gs="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <gs:getGreetingRequest>
            <gs:name>John</gs:name>
        </gs:getGreetingRequest>
      </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
  ```

  we get the following ./output.xml (unformatted):

  ```xml
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:getGreetingResponse xmlns:ns2="http://stackoverflow.com/greeting-soap/">
        <ns2:greeting>
          <ns2:id>1</ns2:id>
          <ns2:content>Hello, John!</ns2:content>
        </ns2:greeting>
      </ns2:getGreetingResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
  ```

---

Everything combined in a [github repository](https://github.com/xerx593/soq21320913):

- [Initial REST version](https://github.com/xerx593/soq21320913/tree/REST_complete)
- [Migrated SOAP version](https://github.com/xerx593/soq21320913)
- [DIFF](https://github.com/xerx593/soq21320913/compare/b36e53ac9034b665f02b11e4f36bc7f06d703181...a0d45a1ce9cd0d06873d896c5e9c45ff5e812234)